# Convert 2D Array to a 3D Space

Tags: python, matrix, plot, multidimensional-array, visualization

I am trying to develop a 3D cube with values from a flat 2D Plane. I am having a lot of difficulty trying to pseudo code it out so I was hoping to get some input from you guys.

I will try my best to express myself through pictures as I am able to visualize what I am trying to achieve.

I have a 2D output based on the **black line** in this figure:
[image]

I have an array with data of amplitude as each index's value i.e (0; 1) -> the 0 is the x coordinate (sample) and 1 as the y coordinate (amplitude) or as another example (~1900; ~0.25).

How do I take this 1 dimensional sequence and extrude it into a 3D picture like below:
[image]

Is there perhaps a library that does such? Or am I going about it the wrong way? The data is from a matched filter output of a sonar signal and I wish to visualize the concentration of the intensity versus where it is located in a sample on a 3D plane. The data has peaks that have inclining and declining gradient slopes before a peak.

I cannot seem to wrap my mind around such a task. Is there a library or a term used to associate what I wish to accomplish?

EDIT: I found this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_3d_surface_plot.htm
But it requires all x, y and z points. Whereas I only have x and y. Additionally I need to be able to access every coordinate (x, y, z) to be able to do range and angle estimation from sample (0, 1) (Transmitted sound where power is highest). I would only like to basically see the top of this though on another 2D axis...

EDIT 2: Following up on a comment below, I would like to convert Figure 1 above into the below image using a library if there exists.

[image]

Thanks so much in advanced!

Comment: Just looking at your example 3D picture I don't see any extruding happening. I see a mistake. You're 3rd tan dot is in the wrong place. It should be perfectly in line with the rest of the dots since all you've done is project the same 2D onto two sides of this cube and then projected lines into the cube from the peeks. You simply put tan dots where the lines project back to the same peek. Except for that 3rd one.  I'm very distracted by this because it in no way provides a visualization of where a sample is on a 3D plane. Whatever that is. I'd love to help you but I can't tell what you want.

Comment: If black and red had been orthogonal signals (they don't look like they are) you could have just added black and red together to get a 3D surface plot.

Comment: @candied_orange Hi Thanks so much for your reply!, I have made edits in hopes to explain better, I feel like Figure 2 is one way of doing it. Do you think there is a better way to achieve Figure 3 from Figure 1?

Comment: if that's what you want look up the term [Heat Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map)